# Tkinter Class "must be str not tuple" TypeError Python

Tags: python, types, tkinter

I'm getting a problem with Tkinter for python, I have a class, `application(root):` root is Tk(), and when I run the class without an `__init__` function, it works okay, but crashes after I quit the program. With the `__init__`, Tkinter tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\stuff\Portable Python 3.2.0.1\application.pyw", line 75, in <module>
    class application(root):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1674, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, I never gave it a tuple. I'm sorry if this is a very idiot question, I tried googling it and came up with nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Did you make absolutely sure nothing you passed it is a tuple by doing `print screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use` on the line before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root` is the base class for `application`. You have provided an instance of `Tk` as the base class, rather than the class itself, ie `application(Tk)`.

It would help if you could show a simple example of your failing code.

Comment: Turns out I didn't even need root or Tk in the base class at all anyway, just a blunder on my part. Thank you!